# What is message_type in yammer "message.json" API?

Tags: c#, api, yammer

What is message_type in yammer "message.json" API?

Basically i am filtering the data from message that which are the private and public messages. Also Which are the messages that is commented?
Is there any way to filter with field in yammer api?

Answer (score 0):

**message_type** lets you know what kind of message was posted.

Examples include:

- **Normal** - This is just a regular message posted by a user
- **System** - This is a message posted by the system, like [NAME] has created the [GROUPNAME]
- **Announcement**
- **Poll**

**in_private_group** and **in_private_message** will help you with your filtering needs

You can tell which messages were replies, by using the **reply_to_id** column

Comment: You should post a link to the references.